# Flutter: Periodically calling list.add() inside initState() causes build() to run but the updated List isn't shown on screen

Tags: flutter

On the screen I expect to see an ever growing list:

- 0
- 1
- 2
- ...

but it's just black.  If I hit CTRL+S in Android Studio all of a sudden the whole list is finally shown.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> list = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('${list.length}');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ListView(
        children: list,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        list.add(Text('${list.length}', key: Key(list.length.toString())));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

At first I thought it was because I wasn't setting **key** property, but I added that and still nothing.

I know the build() property is being triggered every second because I see the print() statement showing the numbers in the debug Run tab output.

What am I missing here?  It's got to be something simple!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting discovery.

What is actually causing your UI to not update is that the reference to the `list` variable is staying the same.

Adding an element, doesn't change the reference and `ListView` seems to work based on references.

Two ways you can confirm this are.

1. Change your `ListView` to a much simpler `Column` widget and voila, it's updating correctly.
2. Change your updation method. Destroy the reference and make a new `List` like this,

   ```
   list = [...list, Text('${list.length}')];
   ```

   and yet again, surprise.

Comment: I would like to add that @KuKu 's solution is one more way to approach this situation. You choose whatever you feel suits you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'key' parameter to 'ListView' widget.
With below code, I confirmed working what you want.
I think that because you add a 'key' to Text widget, 'ListView' widget didn't rebuild.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> list = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('${list.length}');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ListView(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        children: list,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        list.add(Text('${list.length}', key: Key(list.length.toString())));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Or you can do it also by changing 'ListView' to 'ListView.builder'.

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return list[index];
        },
      ),
    );
```